# setOnTouchListener in Transparently Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Please Could You give me a bit of help, I have two activities the main activity (A) and the second activity (B) I made the layout background of activity(B) transparently, so now I can see the components of Activity(A) through Activity(B) until now everything is great, but now I want to access to activity(A) components through Activity(B) that have a transparent background, I used the "setOnTouchListener" to get the touch position  but I have no idea how to set this position that I get to the Activity(A) and make  it act as I touch it directly

my code

```java
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            float x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
            float y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
    
            MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
            m.simulateTouch(motionEvent);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, because when you are in second activity the first activity is paused and even though you can see the elements of first activity you wont be able to access them.
I suggest you to find another way for doing this.

Comment: Thank you, this info helps me to find another way, I do it by using fragment I add fragment on top of another fragment and it works perfectly